# Unable to select drop down list in testcafe

Tags: html, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am new to testcafe and JavaScript and unable to select drop down list by select element id.
Above is my html file

```
<div class="collapse show" id="step-1" style="">
    <div class="card  card-body pb-0">
        <form method="post" class="form-row" id="step-form-1" data- step="2" data-wrapper-key="basic_details">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-12 pl-4 pr-4 w-100">
                <label for="states">Names of state </label>
                <select multiple="" id="states" class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible" label="Names of state"
                        inputtype="multiselect" required="" options="[object Object]" name="states" tabindex="-1"
                        aria-hidden="true">
                    <option value="1">Goa</option>
                    <option value="2">Punjab</option>
                    <option value="3">Maharshtra</option>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my js code

```
test('profile',async t=> {
    const selectStates= Selector('#states')
    const selectOption=selectStates.find('option');
    .click(selectStates)
    .click(selectOption.withText('Punjab'))
}
```

Its not able to even click on drop down button
I am getting error "**The element that matches the specified selector is not visible**".

**I debugged in 0.1x speed and found that the dropdown id is getting clicked but the drop down list is not coming, it keeps showing waiting for element to appear.**

Comment: You can add class or id to option . try it and get with class or id

Comment: okay I will check, thanks

Comment: @safaaytan where do I need to add id, I am getting error
The specified selector does not match any element in the DOM tree.
      option id is #select2-states-result-9h92-10
         | Selector('#states')
       > |   .find('#select2-states-result-9h92-10')
         |   .withText('Punjab')

Comment: Hello, it is a bug. I've reproduced it and created [an issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/5339) on github.

Comment: @Artem Thank you so much, I am stuck since long and trying to debug it where actually the issue is.

Comment: you are also missing a closing `</select>`

Comment: @MehrdadDastgir please ignore closing errors in HTML as it is a huge UI code, I have just copied part of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with testcafe if multiple="" attribute is provided. So I used some another approach instead of selecting options from drop down if you have a textbox type drop down. You can type the option name and hit enter key so that it gets selected.

```
test('profile',async t=> {
    const selectStates= Selector('#states')
    .click(selectStates)
    .typeText(selectStates,'Goa')
    .pressKey('enter')
    .typeText(selectStates,'Punjab')
    .pressKey('enter')
    .pressKey('esc')
    .pressKey('tab')// to go with next selector in the page.
    
}
```

)

The above approach worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In the Select element, multiple="" seems to be the attribute that is triggering the failure